# Get post message from permalink with facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write an app, that will accept a Facebook post's permalink (a public one) and then will return some data, like the post id, the user id and the message it contains, using the Facebook API.

For example, if this is the permalink (the URL you get when you click the time a Facebook post was created):

```
https://www.facebook.com/somePage/posts/16364604654173041076
```

When the posts comes from a user, its permalink is something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1923006774583409&id=100006223158556
```

I want to get the 'somePage' id and the post's message or the user id and the post's message

Is this possible? If not through the facebook API, through some other crawling technique?

Comment: You’d need to parse the URL using regular expressions or similar, to get the page username and the post id from it. Then you need to go look up the page id via the username, and then you can combine both in the form `pageid_postid` to request the details of the specific post.

Comment: Yes i can do this for a page, but what if the owner of the post is a person? Then the url format is something like this: "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=19230067745854543409&id=100006223158564564556" which returns nothing when queried